# I would like to make a few modifications to this forms feature, not sure if we can

Tags: user-interface, umbraco7, umbraco-contour

I want to use the latest version of Umbraco, which has a new "forms" feature (for an additional license fee). I would like to make a few modifications to this forms feature, not sure if we can.

> 1) Encrypt all form results data for storage using strong encryption algorithm.
>
> 2) Decrypt form results data after pulled from storage and displayed decrypted on screen the same way as regular form results would be displayed.
>
> 3) Require a user to enter their Umbraco Password again to view any record. This should popup every single time for every record, requiring the user to re-enter their password again to see the form results. f they view 10 records, they must enter their password 10 times. All password attempts successful or not should be logged.

I was thinking this can be done by creating a new type of form. Currently, when creating a new form in Umbraco, it gives the options of:
Empty Form, Comment Form, and Contact Form.

Can we make a new type called "Secure Form", and this would automatically add the encryption/password functionality described above?

Comment: Umbraco Forms is not actually new, it's a new name for Umbraco Contour. And it isn't open source like the rest of Umbraco, so you probably can't make these kinds of changes yourself. If you'd like to request that HQ consider these changes, you can create an issue/feature request here: http://issues.umbraco.org/issues/CON

Comment: Thanks Jannik Anker For Reply .